# Meaning of wordplay on 'which' and 'witch' in Matt Ruff's Lovecraft Country

Tags: meaning, h-p-lovecraft, matt-ruff, lovecraft-country

I'm reading Matt Ruff's horror novel [*Lovecraft Country*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovecraft_Country_(novel)) (2016). The second chapter, entitled "Dreams of the Which House", is a story about a haunted house.

I found the title plays on Lovecraft's original work, ["The Dreams in the Witch House"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dreams_in_the_Witch_House) (1932).
I guess it's a kind of wordplay because 'which' and 'witch' are homophones.
But still, I can't quite grasp what "the which house" in Matt Ruff's novel  means. Can I interpret it as the witch house but in kind of parodic way?